# Get facebook engagement count for links

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having some problems with facebook engagement count. I' ve never been using this before, so please have some understanding. This is how I current get those things, through PHP obviously:

```
function getNumberOfShares($url, $id) {

        $url_https = "https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.summary(total_count).limit(0)},share&id=https://url.com/part/" . $url."/". $id;

        $fileContents = file_get_contents($url_https);
        $data_share = json_decode($fileContents, true);
        $total = $data_share['share']['share_count'];
        echo $fileContents;
        return $total;
    }
```

I tried something with $access_token but I got permission denied due to lot of requests. I need a way with to do at least 50-100 links per request in intervals. Thank you.

**EDIT AFTER SOME RESEARCH**

```
require_once("fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php");
$default = "111|11A122SAFB";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{111}',
  'app_secret' => '{11A122SAFB}',
  'default_access_token' => $default,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);

$batch = [
    $fb->request('GET', 'https://example.com/part/slug/id&fields=og_object{engagement}'),
    $fb->request('GET', 'https://example.com/part/slug/id&fields=engagement'),
    ];

try {
    $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
  if ($response->isError()) {
    $e = $response->getThrownException();
    echo '<p>Error! Facebook SDK Said: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n";
    echo '<p>Graph Said: ' . "\n\n";
    var_dump($e->getResponse());
  } else {
    echo "<p>(" . $key . ") HTTP status code: " . $response->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br />\n";
    echo "Response: " . $response->getBody() . "</p>\n\n";
    echo "<hr />\n\n";
  }
}
```

Now I got some response like this for two link from batch, and they have different ending:

```
(0) HTTP status code: 200
Response: {"id":"https:\/\/example.com\/part\/slug\/id&fields=og_object{engagement}"}

(1) HTTP status code: 200
Response: {"id":"https:\/\/example.com\/part\/slug\/id&fields=engagement"}
```

Does anybody know how to get shares, likes, comments (engagement) sum with this. Thank you!

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/.

Comment: I did read it. The problem is that this client of mine is pretty big company, with an average number of visits per day around 70 000-100 000. And they are publishing around 100 articles every day. So it' s pretty busy.  I really need some idea :D

Comment: None of that changes the fact that Facebook has rate limits and you're hitting them. Consider, instead, using stuff like Facebook's analytics tools: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/referral-insights/

Comment: They can have all the visits they want - unless they also have active app users, that’s not going to increase the limits. If they don’t have an active Facebook app user base, then using multiple app ids and splitting your requests between those would be the only option. (Probably rather not the one Facebook would want you to use though.)

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to change:

```
https://example.com/part/slug/id&fields=og_object{engagement}
```

to this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{engagement}&id=https://example.com/part/slug/id
```